# How can I find the range of numbers in mongoose node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

example:
User.find( id > 0 && id < 10, function (err, docs) {})

Comment: This is too short a question. There is not enough information to give you an answer without guessing.

Comment: I thought the question was succint and clear and a great answer was provided.. Upvotes for a good question and good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User
  .find({})
  .where('id').gt(0).lt(10)
  .exec(callback);
```

from the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: glad I could help :) you might want to accept the answer by click on the ok sign next to it.